# Stackview not displaying items in interface builder with indeterminate height

Tags: swift

I want to have a Stack View with an image, and 5 items in rows below it.

Not a problem - If I pin the Stack View to the top and bottom of the view I get this (settings: axis - vertical, alignment: fill, distribution: fill proportionally[image: )]

Which gives the final label too much space - of course - because the stack view needs to use all of the space available on the screen.

So I remove the pin to the bottom of the screen.

Success! But I can't see the labels in Interface Builder any longer

[image]

I've tried to get this to work over time and have not found a satisfactory solution. I can set the content compression resistance to 999 for each label but this is not good enough - the image is the most important piece of data and should have priority over these.

Constraints:

[image]

So - is there any way I can have a stack view

### image

### label

### label

### label

and still have the items viewable in Interface builder, or do I have to reset the content compression to unsuitable values to get this to work?

Comment: i think you need a height constraint

Comment: We don't know the height of the image before runtime (it is from an API), so I set a maximum for the image. I could set a maxinum for the Stack View but surely this is equivalent to setting compression resistance?